# d3 text perpendicular to inner radious of an arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I create text perpendicular to the arc. I have donut chart I need to keep text perpendicular to the inner radious of the arc at the center. How can I do it?

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neolivz/d555wdxv/) example i need the hello to be at the center of inner radious and perpendicular to it.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
             .attr('width',400)
             .attr('height',400)
var pi = Math.PI;

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(100)
    .outerRadius(200)
    .startAngle(45 * (pi/180)) //converting from degs to radians
    .endAngle(3) //just radians

var group = svg.append('g')
               .attr("transform","translate(200,200)");


group.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", "red")

group.append('text')
      .text('Hello')
```

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by perpendicular in this case, do you just mean to rotate the text to some arbitrary angle?  If you do, then just apply a `.attr("transform", "rotate(45)")` or something to the text element to rotate it as much or as little as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate the angle of rotation the text. It is just a little bit of trigonometry:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
             .attr('width',400)
             .attr('height',400)
var pi = Math.PI;

var alpha = {begin: 1, end: 4};// radians

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(100)
    .outerRadius(200)
    .startAngle(alpha.begin)// start arc (radians)
    .endAngle(alpha.end);// end arc (radians)

var group = svg.append('g')
               .attr("transform","translate(200,200)");


group.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", "red")

var beta = ((alpha.end - alpha.begin) / 2 + alpha.begin -  Math.PI / 2) * 180 / Math.PI;// chord of arc in degrees
group.append('text').text('Hello')
.attr("transform", "rotate(" + beta + ")");// degrees
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qhh8ufLa/